# Adding my Bmi results to the firebase data

Tags: android, sql, database, firebase

I'm new to android studio literally just 2months, so please don't be harsh on me, I've got a question about adding the user's information to the firebase, for example when he enters his information in the bmi calculator his information will be stored in firebase(I already have connected my app to firebase), here is the bmi java class:

```
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;

import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class Calculator_BMI extends AppCompatActivity {
    EditText height,weight;
    TextView result;
    String calculation,BMIresult;
    Button backBtn;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_calculator__b_m_i);
        weight=findViewById(R.id.weight);
        height=findViewById(R.id.height);
        result=findViewById(R.id.result1);
        //ill be declaring use of the back button
        backBtn=findViewById(R.id.gobackbtn);
        backBtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Toast.makeText(Calculator_BMI.this, "Going Back", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                Intent intent=new Intent(Calculator_BMI.this,home.class);
                startActivity(intent);
            }
        });//end of code for back button

    }

    public void calculateBMI(View view) {
        String s1=weight.getText().toString();
        String s2=height.getText().toString();
        float weightValue=Float.parseFloat(s1);
        float heightValue=Float.parseFloat(s2)/100;
        float bmi=weightValue/(heightValue*heightValue);
        if(bmi<16){
            BMIresult="Severly Underweight";
        }else if(bmi<18.5){
            BMIresult="Underweight";
        }else if(bmi>=18.5 && bmi <=24.9){
            BMIresult="Normal Weight";
        }else if(bmi>=25 && bmi<=29.9){
            BMIresult="Overweight";
        }else if(bmi>=30 && bmi<=35){
            BMIresult="Obese Class I";
        }else if(bmi>=35 && bmi<=40){
            BMIresult="Obese Class II";
        }else{
            BMIresult="Obese Class III";
        }
        calculation="Result:\n\n"+ bmi+"\n"+ BMIresult;
        result.setText(calculation);


    }
}
```

and here is the xml file for it

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    tools:context=".Calculator_BMI">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:text="Weight"
        android:textSize="30dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="200dp"
        />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/weight"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:ems="6"
        android:inputType="textPersonName"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:textAlignment="center"/>
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView3"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:text="Height"
        android:textSize="30dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="20dp"

        />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/height"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:ems="6"
        android:inputType="textPersonName"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:textAlignment="center"/>

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/calculatebutton"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Calculate"
        android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
        android:onClick="calculateBMI"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"

        />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/result1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Result"
        android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:textSize="20dp"
        android:textColor="#000000"
        />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/gobackbtn"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:layout_marginTop="100dp"
        android:text="Go back"
        android:textColor="#800080"
        android:textSize="20sp" />
</LinearLayout>
```

the user has to log in in order to access the firebase so i want everything to be stored specifying the user
what i tired:

- tried to connect it to sql instead of firebase but i just kept getting errors so i stopped
- tried to watch videos to understand but there are none about this

any help will be appreciated

Comment: What exactly in this code doesn't work the way you expect?
Tell us what is wrong with shared code. Do you have any errors?

Comment: @AlexMamo No there isn't anything wrong with the code i just want to know how can i add the weight and height and bmi value that are calculated using this code into firebase

Comment: Are you asking how to [Add Data To Firestore](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/manage-data/add-data#java)? The firebase product you're using isn't indicated bu there's a similar guide for the Realm Time Database.

Comment: @Jay i'm trying to know what can i add to this code to make it save weight height and bmi value to firestore

Comment: Sure! Read through the documentation on writing data, as linked above. Then write some code and if you get stuck, ask a question and include your Firebase code.